# AWS detect file and registry changes on EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, registrykey

Are there any native AWS tools to detect key file changes and registry changes for EC2 (linux and widnows)?

Comment: you mean the registry on the windows machine or *some* file on that machine? At that point AWS is basically out of the picture, you can do whatever you would do on your local windows / linux machine. Or are you talking about something else changing and notifying - if so: what exactly?

Comment: Agree it's out of AWS. Just wondering if AWS has some native solution that can be configured to monitor changes for a list of files (windows and linux EC2s) and changes to windows registry (Windows EC2)

Comment: No, AWS does not supply such a tool. It does supply the ability to run remote commands on instances ([AWS Systems Manager Run Command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/execute-remote-commands.html)), which you could use to trigger a script to search for such information.